# Where to put WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why can't I put WHERE clause after ORDER BY?

```
SELECT column1
FROM myTable
ORDER BY column2
WHERE column2 = 5
```

Is there any standard reference? Where can i get a SQL standard draft?

Comment: "Is there any standard reference?"  Are you kidding?  Please say you were just kidding.  Or, perhaps, MSDN was down or Google was broken.  The SQL standard hasn't changed much in the last 20 years and is really, really well documented.  You were kidding, right?  If so, perhaps you should edit your question to remove that comment. It makes your question appear foolish.

Comment: Actually, the standard has gone through several revisions.  First released in 1986, then again in 1989, 1992, 1999, 2003 with 2006 and 2008 versions still in ratification.  Overall the changes have been small but significant. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Comment: The only form of SQL I ever came across where the above is valid was FoxPro - and I then had to "unlearn" it.

Comment: No doubt, the SQL in the OP is wrong.  I was simply pointing out the pot and kettle.

Answer (score 3):

Swap the last two lines:

```
SELECT column1
FROM myTable
WHERE column2 = 5
ORDER BY column2
```

Your `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE` statement is the data you extract, and the `ORDER BY` sorts it.

But sorting that query would be pointless, as you already know that `column2` is equal to `5`.

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` clause should go before the `ORDER BY` clause.  [Here's a good article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) showing the format of a `SELECT` statement in T-SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The details of the SELECT syntax are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx

Answer (score 1):

That's because SQL has a syntax order, same happens with functions on most languages, what will happen then if you switch the params? you won't get the expected results...

Here's a quick guide reference for the basic SQL Statements and the order of Syntax: http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

The Standards are discussed near the end of this document http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL though you may have to pay for a copy of the official standards document from ISO.